# I just Cant Deploy a Laravel 5 App

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.5

Im trying to deploy a laravel 5 aplication.

So, im using a LAMP + PHPADMIN image from digital ocean

I installed git and downloaded my laravel 5 aplication, after this, I installed composer and used the command "composer install".

So, when I try to acces localhost/myapp/public its only a white screen and when I try some route I get 404 from Apache.

What did I Missed?

Comment: Make sure all files and directories at localhost/myapp have read permissions for your Apache user. Also directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your Apache user.

Comment: I did chmd -R 777 to storage.

Comment: just to make sure you did `chmod` and not `chmd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the **mod_rewrite** module.

If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Already did this, and the other routes are going to 404 apache error

Comment: this .httacces where in composer/cache is this right?

Comment: Did you try the following url : localhost/myapp/public/index.php ?

A .htaccess under myapp/public is necessary for pretty urls only

Comment: Now i only get this

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Set the debug option to true in your app, you need to turn debugging on to see the actual error.

The amount of error detail your application displays through the browser is controlled by the app.debug configuration option in your **config/app.php** configuration file. By default, this configuration option is set to respect the APP_DEBUG environment variable, which is stored in your .env file.

For local development, you should set the APP_DEBUG environment variable to true. In your production environment, this value should always be false.